# How to horizontally position elements for a pagination toolbar using Boostrap?

Tags: angularjs, html, css, styling

I'm working on an AngularJS project and in one of my views I have a table that will have pagination implemented on it. I want the controls for the pagination to be as follows:

- Stacked horizontally, to have a Previous button, a text indicating the page of total of pages, and a Next button.
- A select containing the number of elements per page desired to visualize on the table, and a text just saying "elements per page"
- A text input to enter the number of page, and a Go to button that will load the indicated page.
- All of these have to be sorted horizontally.

I defined this components like this in my view:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
        <li ><a href="#" ng-click="uc.previousPage()">Anterior</a></li>
        <li ><a>1 de 10 páginas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" ng-click="uc.nextPage()">Siguiente</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control"  ng-model="uc.defaultSelect" ng-options="n for n in uc.elementsPerPage" ></select>
      <label>elementos por página</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ir a página..." />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Ir</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the end result I'm getting looks like this

[image: Wrong positioning]

The nav buttons look completely off line, the select is too big and it's pushing the label to a new line, the one that looks fine is the go to page input.

What kind of styling can I use with Bootstrap to achieve the look I desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I had to give up on using the `pagination`style and changed to `button-group`, I removed some labels and ended up with this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 btn-group">

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="uc.previousPage()">Anterior</button>
      <a class="btn btn-default disabled">1 de 10 páginas</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="uc.nextPage()">Siguiente</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm"  ng-model="uc.defaultSelect" ng-options="n as (n + ' por página') for n in uc.elementsPerPage" ></select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" ng-model="uc.page" class="form-control" placeholder="Ir a página..." />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="uc.goToPage()">Ir</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Now I get this in my view:

[image: Desired result]

I can just add some color to it if as necessary and I just got a pretty looking pagination toolbar.